# Zoom and Fade Custom Segue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uistoryboard, segue

I'm trying to create a custom iOS segue that will have an effect similar to the one seen when starting an app on iOS 7. Within my app, I want the use to tap a button and the segue be a zoom into that button that reveals the view. How can I do this?